# Which number system can be one-to-one correspondent to Time?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, time-series

Recently I've learned the concept of one-to-one correspondence and I just naively thought time might be one-to-one correspondent to the Real Number system since we usually plot the time series in $ \in \Bbb R$

First, is it correct? or just we need somewhat assumption to postulate "Time is one-to-one correspondent to $\Bbb R$ ?

Second, if so, How could one prove it?

Comment: You should first give a precise definition of what you call "time".

Comment: @E.Bellec Well.. is there any widely-accepted def of time among mathematicians? I don't know so I am asking because from my young days every one uses $\Bbb R$ as time, so there might be some rationalle provided already.

Comment: I'm a physicist, so I can't say anything about the mathematics community. On the other hand, in physics, no proper definition of time is given. And no experiments can tell you if time is continuous or discrete with an extremely small time step.

Comment: @E.Bellec thanks for not-yet-definiteness of time in physics.. could you give me your rough guess why people prefer to use time just like one-to-one correspondent to real number?

Comment: Because, when comparing with experiments, theoretical calculation with continuous time or discrete time with very tiny step gives you something similar. And integration is often easier than a sum.

Comment: The usual way to do in physics is "assume it's continuous, as simple as possible, and if you get into trouble then start to think on the hypothesis you made."